# Issue with initializing Vectors in C++

Tags: c++11, vector

I'm trying to initialize a vector in visual studio this way :

```
const vector <int> A {1,2,3,4,5};
```

and its giving me an error.  The error says :

"error C2470: 'A' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body"

Can anyone please tell me why i'm getting this error?

Comment: Which compiler version?

Comment: i am using visual studio 2012

Comment: till VS2012, intializer_list is not supported and due to that you are getting this compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned that VS2012 does not support initializer_list and hence we get the compilation error. You can use the following to get the almost same thing.

```
#include<vector>
#include <iterator>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    const std::vector <int> A(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
    for(const auto& i: A)
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: so when you're doing, vector<int>A(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr)), its basically initializing vector A with all the values in array 'arr' from beginning to end?..

Comment: @psj01: yes that correct. This is initialization using global begin() and end() function which was introduced in C++11 standard.The advantage of this approach is it is applicable for default array(as in this case) and for all standard container provided.

Answer (score 1):

The way which you are using to initialize vector is not supported by C++98...
The support has been provided for  `initializer list constructor` in C++11..

so instead you can use below code...

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> A(arr, arr+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
```